# Passar valor de variáveis entre as Classes

Tags: java, classes, parâmetros

Gostaria de passar os valores armazenados nas variáveis da parte1 para a parte2 para fazer a validação do maior valor digitado.

PARTE 1:

```
public class SEP_06_parte1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("Digite 10 valores ");

            int y1 = input.nextInt();
            int y2 = input.nextInt();
            int y3 = input.nextInt();
            int y4 = input.nextInt();
            int y5 = input.nextInt();
            int y6 = input.nextInt();
            int y7 = input.nextInt();
            int y8 = input.nextInt();
            int y9 = input.nextInt();
            int y10 = input.nextInt();

        SEP_06_parte2 lernumeros = new SEP_06_parte2();
        lernumeros.determineMaior();

    }
}
```

PARTE 2:

```
public class SEP_06_parte2{
    public void determineMaior(){
        int maiorResultado = maximum(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10);
                System.out.print("Maior Numero: " + maiorResultado);
        }
        public static int maximum( int y1 , int y2, int y3, int y4, int y5, int y6, int y7, int y8, int y9, int y10)
            {
                int maximumValue = y1;
                if ( y2 > maximumValue )
                maximumValue = y2;
                if ( y3 > maximumValue )
                maximumValue = y3;
                if ( y4 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y4;
                if ( y5 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y5;
                if ( y6 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y6;
                if ( y7 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y7;
                if ( y8 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y8;
                if ( y9 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y9;
                if ( y10 > maximumValue )
                    maximumValue = y10;
                return maximumValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código está bem confuso e maior do que deveria. Parece haver também uso inconsistente do `static`, no seu caso provavelmente tudo deveria ser `static` na "parte 2" e aí nem precisaria criar uma instância na "parte 1". Na verdade vejo várias coisas desnecessárias no código. Vou me concentrar só na sua pergunta.

Você entende como funciona parâmetros? Você entende que variáveis existem só dentro de um [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) definido e que você só pode passar seus valores para outro escopo através de parâmetros?

Existem várias formas de fazer isto. Vou colocar as duas principais.

Você pode fazer com que o método `determineMaior()` receba parâmetros também, assim pode passar todas as variáveis da "parte 1" para ele. Desta forma:

```
public void determineMaior(int y1 , int y2, int y3, int y4, int y5, int y6, int y7, int y8, int y9, int y10){
    int maiorResultado = maximum(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10);
    System.out.print("Maior Numero: " + maiorResultado);
}
```

E claro que a chamada no `main()` seria:

```
lernumeros.determineMaior(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/Max.java).

Talvez fosse mais interessante usar um *array* ou alguma coleção para guardar estes valores ao invés de várias variáveis. Talvez devesse receber uma *array* como parâmetro ou pelo menos [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). E aí usaria um *loop* para verificar qual é o maior ao invés de tantos `if`s. Desta forma ficaria mais curto e mais flexível.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, o que eu desejo é fazer um programa que veja qual o maior numero entre 10 valores digitados pelo usuário, estou começando agora a trabalhar com LOO, sempre trabalhei com desenvolvimento Front-end por isso não domino ainda o Java, mas estou treinando para isso... ^^ Novamente Obrigado!