# Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?

Tags: terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, escopo-de-variáveis, tempo-de-vida

O que é escopo?

O que é tempo de vida?

Eles se confundem?

Visibilidade tem alguma coisa a ver com isto também?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Eles podem se confundir em algumas situações, mas são conceitos completamente diferentes. Há casos que o tempo de vida é ou parece ser igual ao escopo, então parece que é a mesma coisa.

## [Escopo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

Este é um conceito de tempo de compilação. Escopo (pelo menos o estático) existe no texto do código fonte, você o descobre lendo o código. Ele é um indicador do tempo de vida de uma vinculação de um nome com um valor. Em geral isto se refere à variáveis. Ele se refere em que partes do código a variável é visível/acessível.

Outros identificadores têm escopo também, como os *labels* de controle de fluxo ou funções, ou mesmo classes. Nem vou falar de parâmetros e constantes que são muito parecidos com variáveis.

Então podemos dizer que nesse contexto a **visibilidade** é um sinônimo de escopo. O termo visibilidade pode ter outro significado em outros contextos. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque não é o foco, mas há casos que a visibilidade pode ser controlada deixando algum membro exposto para acesso externo ou não.

Obviamente que um trecho de código não pode acessar uma variável que está fora de escopo. O fato de uma variável ser declarada não significa que ela está sempre disponível. Dependendo do local onde está declarada ela pode estar visível para o código ou não (note que a visibilidade do que está escrito é outra coisa).

Dentro do mesmo escopo não pode ter duas variáveis com mesmo nome. Se tentar fazer isto, no fundo será a mesma variável.

Há momentos que duas variáveis de mesmo nome podem estar "em escopo". As linguagens possuem regras para determinar qual das duas variáveis será usada e normalmente provêm algum mecanismo para referenciar-se à outra se for necessário. Aí o programador é obrigado a desambiguar o que pretende.

Muitas vezes chamamos isso de escopo léxico ou estático. Há controvérsias se pode ser usado corretamente neste contexto.

Em alguns casos o escopo pode ser dinâmico e definido em tempo de execução. Isso é raro, específico para cada linguagem que o adota e confuso, por isso não pretendo aprofundar.

#### Funções

O escopo mais comum é o da função. A maioria das linguagens são bem estritas quanto a isto. Uma variável declarada dentro de uma função (ou método, claro) é considerada local e só pode ser acessada ali dentro. Qualquer tentativa de acessá-la fora causará um erro. Outras partes do código desconhecem completamente a sua existência.

Lembrando que [*closures*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) são funções e podem capturar variáveis criadas em outro escopo mais externo, aumentando o tempo de vida do seu **valor**.

#### Blocos

Outro escopo comum é o do bloco. Isto pode ser um laço, condicional, exceção ou outro tipo de bloco. Em casos de blocos que estão relacionados (`if/else`) algumas linguagens tratam como se fosse apenas um bloco único.

É possível declarar duas variáveis com mesmo nome em um trecho desde que elas estejam em escopos diferentes. Apesar de usar o mesmo nome, as variáveis são completamente diferentes. Vamos dizer que um local não pode ter duas pessoas com mesmo nome, então se tiver um "João", qualquer referência a este nome será a esta pessoa. Quando esta pessoa sair e entrar outra, o mesmo nome "João" passa ser usado para outra pessoa. Um exemplo típico é o uso para controle de laços de repetição. Alguns programadores que não entendem este conceito tendem a criar uma variável para cada laço. Não é necessário, um laço é um escopo, e o outro é o um escopo novo, as variáveis não se confundem.

É "boa prática" :D fazer a variável ter o menor escopo possível.

#### Expressão

É comum poder definir um bloco mais específico ainda, em geral uma expressão específica, um bloco solto que não seja um controle de fluxo.

#### Módulo ou arquivo

O escopo pode ser uma classe, módulo ou algo do tipo. Variáveis que estão fora de funções, mas fazem parte de alguma estrutura de dados.

Um tipo específico pode ser um arquivo. Algumas linguagens não possuem grande granularidade para especificar um escopo amplo e o arquivo serve para isto.

#### Global

É válido em qualquer lugar. Costuma gerar confusão e deve ser usado com parcimônia, especialmente em aplicações grandes.

#### *Linkage*

Há linguagens que permitem que uma mesma variável ou identificador possa ser declarada(o) em dois locais diferentes se referindo ao mesmo valor ou propósito. É uma forma de colocar em escopo algo que está em outro escopo sem criar algo novo.

## Tempo de vida

Este é um conceito de tempo de execução. Pode estar relacionado à [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), mas também a objetos em geral. Se refere ao armazenamento de dados.

Se for uma variável o tempo de vida se refere ao tempo que ela está disponível para acesso, ou pelo menos quando ela tem um valor com significado para o código. Em algumas situações é igual ao escopo.

É importante diferenciar [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), que é só o nome dado a um valor, conforme já definido, e do valor a que ela se refere. O tempo de vida tem mais a ver com o valor. Um valor pode sobreviver mesmo que a variável morra, uma variável pode mudar seu valor, portanto, eventualmente, ter um tempo de vida maior que o valor.

Sobrevive quando:

- o valor é retornado no fim de uma função
- o valor é atribuído para outra variável em escopo maior (pode ser outra estrutura de dados)
- o valor é atribuído dentro de uma *closure* ou mecanismo com efeito semelhante.

Há o tempo de vida do valor da variável, que pode ser apenas uma referência e tem o tempo de vida do objeto que ela se refere.

Em geral quando uma variável sai de escopo, se seu valor (mesmo referenciado) não estiver vinculado à alguma coisa, seu tempo de vida acaba, ou pelo menos torna-se inacessível. Mas há casos em que o objeto passe para outro proprietário, mantendo seu tempo de vida.

A alocação da memória para a variável/objeto pode ter várias estratégias e só coincidem se for de interesse da aplicação/linguagem. Assim como o [local onde a alocação será feita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Linguagens com coletores de lixo costumam manter dados alocados mesmo após o tempo de vida dele acabar. *Pools* de alocação podem ser usados.

Alguns tipos de dados são sempre estáticos e tem o tempo de vida por toda duração da aplicação. É o caso de funções (o código em si) e variáveis estáticas.

## Exemplo

```cs
class Teste {
    int x = 5; //escopo da classe, tempo de vida de acordo com a instância
    StringBuilder txt; //o mesmo
    int Metodo(int y) { //parâmetro existe dentro da função escopo/lifetime 
        var x = 2; //note que há ambiguidade com a variável da classe
        var t = new StringBuilder(10); //variável e objeto locais vivem até a função
        for (var z = 0; z < 10; z++) { //só existe dentro deste bloco
            WriteLine(this.x * x + y * z); //desambigua e usa todas variáveis
        } //z morre aqui
        //uma tentativa de acessar z aqui produziria erro
        for (var z = 0; z < 10; z++) { //este z é diferente do outro
            t.Append(z.ToString()); //declarada fora, continuará existindo no fim do bloco
        } //z morre aqui
        txt = t; //a variável vai morrer o seu objeto sobreviverá em txt
        return x; //o valor será copiado para algum lugar, será um novo objeto igual
    } //aqui morrem x (local), y, t (não seu objeto, qua ainda tem referência)
}
static class Program {
    static int x = 10; //escopo desta classe tempo de vida da aplicação
    static void Main() { //só existe dentro desta classe
        StringBuilder t; //vive por toda função
        { //inicia um novo escopo
            var y = new Teste(); //variável e objeto têm escopo e tempo de vida deste bloco
            x = y.Metodo(3); //este x nada tem a ver com o x da outra classe, nem poderia
            t = y.txt; //o texto ainda viverá
        } //y morre aqui, seu objeto precisa viver mais porque tem uma referência para ele
        WriteLine(t); //o texto 0123456789 será impresso, ainda vive
        //não é possível acessar o conteúdo de y mais, mesmo o objeto estando vivo
        //o escopo acabou,só a referência previamente existente ainda pode acessar o objeto
    } //aqui morre t e finalmente o objeto criado por new Teste()
} //note que x não segura uma referência para o objeto, seu resultado é uma cópia
//código para demonstração simples, não faça isto em casa
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Scope.cs).

O exato funcionamento depende da linguagem.

Comment: cada post seu é uma aula haha :P

Answer (score -3):

A "visibilidade" de um identificador determina as partes do programa nas quais pode ser feita uma referência a ele (seu "escopo"). Um identificador é visível (ou seja, pode ser usado) somente nas partes de um programa abrangidas por seu "escopo", que pode ser limitado (em ordem crescente de restrição) ao arquivo, à função, ao bloco ou ao protótipo de função em que aparece. O escopo de um identificador é a parte do programa na qual o nome pode ser usado. Às vezes, isso é chamado de "escopo léxico". Há quatro tipos de escopo: função, arquivo, bloco e protótipo de função.

O “tempo de vida” é o período durante a execução de um programa em que uma variável ou uma função existe. A duração de armazenamento de identificador determina seu tempo de vida.

Comment: btw, fonte: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-language/scope-and-visibility?view=msvc-170