# Como é identificado um bloco de escopo em uma linguagem como Python?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, parser

Como uma linguagem identifica um bloco onde não usa chaves para abrir e fechar?

```
function exemplo(){
  // ...
}
```

Acredito que no exemplo acima o *parser* crie um bloco de escopo a partir das chaves, mas em uma linguagem como Python

```
def exemplo():
  // ...
```

Ele leva em consideração o nível de indentação como prioridade?

Como é feito a leitura? Como é gerado?

Comment: Primeiro, o que é uma linguagem *duck typing*? O que isto tem a ver com o escopo ou o bloco de comando? Você quer saber como o Python identifica o começo e fim do bloco de comando?

Comment: Isso mesmo, como é identificado o começo e o fim de um escopo. fiz a pergunta sem ler nada sobre Duck Typing apenas oque eu pensava que seria. Lendo esse artigo https://osantana.me/duck-typing/ vi que ta totalmente errado esse titulo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma linguagem como Python, assim como diversas linguagens funcionais, só para citar algumas, a delimitação de um bloco de comandos (que pode gerar novo [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) ou não) é feita basicamente pela indentação (o deslocamento de espaços do início da linha).

Quando o *parser* identifica que há espaços adicionais no início da linha em relação a linha anterior ele considera que houve um *indent*. Quando ele identificar que uma nova linha voltou para a coluna anterior que estava antes no nível anterior (ele vai empilhando isto), então ele considera que houve um *dedent*. A marca de *indent* funciona como abre chave e a marca de *dedent* funciona como o fecha chave. Você pode não estar vendo nada mas o compilador sabe que tem uma marca ali que foi calculada.

Obviamente é preciso formatar bem o código para tudo dar certo e o *parser* "não se perder". Claro que algumas regras podem facilitar isto.

O Python ainda usa os dois pontos na linha anterior ao bloco para identificar que ela terá um bloco adiante o que até facilita o *parser* pelo menos entender melhor qual era a intenção e se antecipar (*lookahead*).