# Dispose aninhado é necessário?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, using

Tenho o seguinte código hipotético.

```
using (var QDR = new DAL.teste())
{
   //codigos
   using (var QDR1 = new DAL.teste1())
   {
      //codigos
      using (var QDR2 = new DAL.teste2())
      {
            // códigos
      }
   }
 }
```

O código acima é valido porém **seria necessário colocar todos os objetos dentro do using**? visto que no primeiro `using` ele não liberaria toda as variáveis em memória?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `Dispose()` não libera variáveis, ele libera recursos.

Os objetos em memória (não confundir com os recursos) só são liberados pelo [*garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101) em momento que só cabe a ele decidir. Variáveis "são liberadas" quando o objeto que a contém é liberado, ou se for local é no momento que encerra o escopo dela. [Entenda mais sobre escopo e tempo e vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Cada `using` chamará o `Dispose()` apenas do recurso que ele criou, nada a mais. Então ele é necessário, mas pode fazer simplificadamente.

Dependendo do uso é possível simplificar este código colocando tudo em um bloco só, neste caso é só fazer:

```
using (var QDR = new DAL.teste())
using (var QDR1 = new DAL.teste1())
using (var QDR2 = new DAL.teste2()) {
    // etc
}
```

Mudei a classe (`MemoryStream`) só para facilitar e mandei gerar o IL só para ter uma noção do que isto executa:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 61 (0x3d)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream,
            [1] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream,
            [2] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
        IL_000c: stloc.1
        IL_000d: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
        IL_0012: stloc.2
        IL_0013: nop
        IL_0014: nop
        IL_0015: leave.s IL_0022
        IL_0017: ldloc.2
        IL_0018: brfalse.s IL_0021
        IL_001a: ldloc.2
        IL_001b: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_0020: nop
        IL_0021: endfinally
        IL_0022: leave.s IL_002f
        IL_0024: ldloc.1
        IL_0025: brfalse.s IL_002e
        IL_0027: ldloc.1
        IL_0028: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_002d: nop
        IL_002e: endfinally
        IL_002f: leave.s IL_003c
        IL_0031: ldloc.0
        IL_0032: brfalse.s IL_003b
        IL_0034: ldloc.0
        IL_0035: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_003a: nop
        IL_003b: endfinally
        IL_003c: ret

        Try IL_0013-IL_0017 Finally IL_0017-IL_0022
        Try IL_000d-IL_0024 Finally IL_0024-IL_002f
        Try IL_0007-IL_0031 Finally IL_0031-IL_003c
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20c4
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

Inclusive em C# 8 isso nem é necessário, o bloco se tornou opcional (você ainda pode usar se necessário ou achar que fica melhor, eu acho que não fica, mas quem se acostumou...):

```
using var QDR = new DAL.teste();
using var QDR1 = new DAL.teste1();
using var QDR2 = new DAL.teste2();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Dispose.cs).

O bloco em que essas três variáveis foram declaradas irá determinam o fim e onde a liberação do recurso ocorrerá.

Comment: no caso do meu código não daria para agrupar, mas ainda sim vale a pena um using para cada? ele não liberaria os recursos já no primeiro using? visto que ele está dentro dele?

Comment: Não vejo porque não poderia, mas não posso falar só por este trecho. Só posso repetir o que já está na resposta, cada um libera só o recurso que ele criou, nada a mais. Não existe isto de estar dentro.