# DataReader abre e dá erro por não fechar

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

Tenho um `DataReader` no meu website para ler os dados que o banco traz. Ai quando duas pessoas entram em computadores diferentes, e até navegadores diferentes, abre uma conexão, porem na hora que vou ler alguns dados o VS me retorna um erro

> Já existe um DataReader aberto associado a este Command que deve ser fechado primeiro

Teria alguma coisa que possa mudar para varias pessoas conseguirem acessar ao mesmo tempo? Fechar o DataReader?

```
 public static List<dMovimentoUser> listar_lancamentos(string conexao)
    {
        List<dMovimentoUser> carrinho = new List<dMovimentoUser>();
        Dados objDados = new Dados();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_lancamentos_internos_listar", objDados.abreConexao());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conexao", conexao);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        objDados.abreConexao();

        try
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dMovimentoUser ct = new dMovimentoUser();
                ct.codigo = reader["código"].ToString();
                ct.descricao = reader["produto"].ToString();
                ct.data = reader["data"].ToString();
                ct.hora = reader["hora"].ToString();
                ct.operacao = reader["operacao"].ToString();
                ct.qtd = float.Parse(reader["quantidade"].ToString());
                ct.historico = reader["historico"].ToString();
                carrinho.Add(ct);
            }
            return carrinho;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro encontrado: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            objDados.fechaConexao();
        }
    }
```

Comment: vc está usando um SqlConnection estatico dentro do seu `Dados`?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Esse código tem alguns problemas.

```
public static List<dMovimentoUser> listar_lancamentos(string conexao) {
    var carrinho = new List<dMovimentoUser>();
    varobjDados = new Dados();
    //temo que esse abreConexao deve estar causando problema também
    using var command = new SqlCommand("usp_lancamentos_internos_listar", objDados.abreConexao();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conexao", conexao);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); //o using garante o fechamento
    //esse abreConexao não deve ter sido escrito do jeito correto também.
    objDados.abreConexao(); //de novo? isso está muito errado
    //já que não está fazendo nada útil com a exceção, é melhor não tratá-la aqui
    //se vai relançar a exceção sem resolver nada, não capture, principalmente Exception
    while (reader.Read()) {
        var ct = new dMovimentoUser();
        ct.codigo = reader["código"].ToString(); //acho que isso pode ser simplificado
        ct.descricao = reader["produto"].ToString();
        ct.data = reader["data"].ToString();
        ct.hora = reader["hora"].ToString();
        ct.operacao = reader["operacao"].ToString();
        ct.qtd = float.Parse(reader["quantidade"].ToString());
        ct.historico = reader["historico"].ToString();
        carrinho.Add(ct);
    }
    return carrinho;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/DataReader.cs).

Leia outras perguntas para entender melhor o funcionamento do `using` e o jeito correto de gerenciar recursos "que precisam ser fechados":

- [Método para executar ao destruir instância de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101535/101)
- [Dispose aninhado é necessário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137310/101)
- [Documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se ainda não entender sugiro fazer perguntas mais específicas sobre o assunto, ler um bom livro que ensine fazer corretamente ou procurar um bom curso que ensine gerenciar recursos sem risco de mantê-los abertos.

Comment: Me disseram que o static está fazendo isso. Ai na hora em tiro o static da minha string de conexão, meu SqlConnection dá erro. Seria esse static talvez?

Comment: Esse seria minha string de conexão public class Dados
    {
private static string stringConexao = @"Data Source=BF-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS,49258;Initial Catalog=SUPERBF;User ID=sa;Password=bf@12345;";
private static SqlConnection conexaoDecup = new SqlConnection(stringConexao);
public SqlConnection fechaConexao()
{
if (conexaoDecup.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
conexaoDecup.Close();
}
return conexaoDecup;
}
public SqlConnection abreConexao()
{
if (conexaoDecup.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
conexaoDecup.Open();
}
return conexaoDecup;
}
        #endregion
    }

Comment: É possível que isso seja problema também, mas não necessariamente. Aí a gente entre em um contexto bem maior do que está na pergunta. E pode ser que toda a aplicação esteja errada. Tirando ele dá erro porque tem que mudar várias outras coisas para funcionar. Esse código do comentário tem o mesmo problema que eu falei na resposta. Minha resposta ainda é válida, com ou sem `static`. Você precisa entender vários conceitos para fazer certo.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Depois de muito tempo, agora lembrei de vir aqui mostrar a solução. Antes eu esta criando uma variável puxando minha string de conexão. E depois eu a inseria no SqlConnection. Para resolver esse meu problema, eu apenas coloquei essa minha string de conexão direto no SqlConnection. Ficando assim:

```
//O que dá erro
private static string stringConexao = @"Data Source=instacia;Initial Catalog=banco;User ID=sa;Password=******; MultipleActiveResultSets = true"
private static SqlConnection conexaoDecup = new SqlConnection(stringConexao);

//O que deu certo
private SqlConnection conexaoDecup = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=instacia;Initial Catalog=banco;User ID=sa;Password=******; MultipleActiveResultSets = true");
```

É isso. Obrigado aos que tentaram me ajudar.