# É errado usar variáveis comuns dentro de uma classe PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

É uma forma errônea de POO? Eu posso usar apenas atributos dentro da minha classe? Posso usar variáveis do tipo `$Variavel`, quando necessário?

Digo, não usar o `public $variavel`, ou `var $variavel`, `private $variavel`.

Falo que usar variáveis comuns, só o `$variavel` dentro de alguns métodos, quando se fizer necessário.

Estou perguntando se posso usar variáveis normais/locais do tipo `$var`, sem `public`, `private`, `var` ou qualquer modificador de acesso, em métodos de uma classe.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo pra gente entender melhor do que está falando. Quer dizer, sem `var`, `public`, `private`, nada?

Comment: Sobre "ser errado" já adianto, a única coisa errada mesmo em programação, é usar as coisas sem saber. Se souber o que está fazendo, pode misturar POO com procedural, misturar C com C++ e cometer o "sacrilégio" de não usar `.h` ainda por cima, usar ISO-8859-1 quando for mais conveniente, usar um `goto` bem posicionado ou um return no meio da função, e assim por diante. Seria legal você [edit] a pergunta e colocar um exemplo, e descrever melhor qual é a dúvida, assim o pessoal pode dar respostas técnicas, se existem vantagens reais, desvantagens reais, ou se é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Usar/declarar variáveis locais em métodos não tem problema nem é errado.

Comment: Parte da pergunta fala em atributos de classe, parte fala de variáveis de métodos, de qual está falando efetivamente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não há problemas e tampouco é errado.

O que pode ser "errôneo" é usar variáveis locais para recursos que poderiam ser compartilhados.

Exemplo de algo nada inteligente:

```
class foo() {

    private $a;

    private function X() {
        $data = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
        //afz uns cambalacho aqui e tal
    }

    private function Y() {
        $data = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
        // faz as firulas..
    }
}

$c = new foo();
$c->X();
$c->Y();
```

Isso é um exemplo de caso errôneo. Pois no método X() há uma variável local que recebeu uma informação, fez a leitura de um arquivo.

No método Y() há também o mesmo processo. É algo redundante e está consumindo recursos desnecessários.

Se vai executar ambos os métodos na mesma instância, então o ideal seria compartilhar informação já processada.

```
class foo() {

    private $a;
    private $data = null;

    private function X() {
        $this->D();
        //faz uns cambalacho aqui e tal
    }

    private function Y() {
        $this->D();
        // faz as firulas..
    }
    private function D() {
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
        }
    }
}

$c = new foo();
$c->X();
$c->Y();
```

Lógico, considerando que o dado no arquivo é estático e não precisa ter preocupação se a informação foi modificada no meio tempo entre a chamada dos métodos.

Basicamente basta prestar atenção a redundâncias.

Todavia, se está tentando dizer algo como usar as variáveis dentro da classe e fora do corpo dos métodos, então não faz sentido, pois apenas podem ser feitas declarações.

```
class Foo(){
     $v = 1; //isso é permitido mas em versões recentes exige-se a declaração da visibilidade (public, private, static)

}
```

<sub>*Os exemplos acima são meramente didáticos.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> É errado usar variáveis comuns dentro de uma classe?

Não é questão de ser errado, simplesmente não é permitido.

> É uma forma errônea de POO?

O que? Usar variáveis que se parecem com locais na classe? Isso não é possível como dito antes. Ou está falando de variáveis em métodos como em parte da pergunta?

Se for isso, nada tem a ver com orientação a objetos. As variáveis da classe podem estar relacionadas com OOP. Então não cabe dizer se o uso em métodos é certo ou errado pensando em OOP.

O fato é que as variáveis devem ter o [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) mais restrito possível sempre. Se todo programador aprendesse isso os códigos já ficariam bem melhores.

> Eu posso usar apenas atributos dentro da minha classe? Posso usar variáveis do tipo `$Variavel`, quando necessário?

Fora do método, mas dentro da classe tem que haver um indicador que aquilo é uma variável usando um dos modificadores de visibilidade `public`, `private`, `protected`, ou o obsoleto `var`, além do `static`. Então na classe só pode algo assim:

```
public $var1;
private $var2;
protected var3;
static $var4;
```

> Digo, não usar o `public $variavel`, ou `var $variavel`, `private $variavel`.

Não pode.

> Falo que usar variáveis comuns, só o `$variavel` dentro de alguns métodos, quando se fizer necessário.

Agora estamos falando de outra coisa. Aqui a pergunta muda de variáveis de classe para variáveis de métodos. Precisa conceituar corretamente. Sem entender o conceito fica difícil fazer qualquer coisa correta.

Poder, pode. Se o algoritmo não exigir estado intermediário dentro do método, tudo bem. Faça o que tiver que fazer. Na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) a maioria dos exemplos não usam variáveis locais.

Dentro de métodos você **só pode** criar variáveis locais. Você não pode declarar variáveis dentro de métodos com os modificadores citados. Estes modificadores de visibilidade só fazem sentido em variáveis da classe.

Variáveis locais são privadas ao método sempre, por isso recebem o nome de "locais", seu acesso é bem restrito ao local que ela existe. Seu propósito é guardar estado ao algoritmo interno ao método. Funciona igual a qualquer função. Elas nada tem a ver com as variáveis de instância ou puramente de classe (estáticas).

Um parâmetro não deixa de ser uma variável local.

Mas pode acessar os membros da classe. Se a palavra "usar" está escrita nesse sentido, então pode. Lembre-se que para acessar as variáveis de classe na verdade está acessando a variável `$this`. O que muita gente não sabe é que um método sempre tem um parâmetro escondido chamado `$this`, por isso consegue acessar as variáveis da classe, no fundo você está recebendo o objeto nessa variável e aí acessa seus membros através dela.

> Estou perguntando se posso usar variáveis normais/locais do tipo `$var`, sem `public`, `private`, `var` ou qualquer modificador de acesso, em métodos de uma classe

Como já dito antes, a palavra "usar" é ambígua. Criar (declarar) só pode variáveis assim. Acessar ou modificar o valor pode fazer **também** nos membros declarados na classe.

Um exemplo simplificado (não é adequado fazer exatamente isso):

```
class Produto {
    private $preco; //variável de classe
    public function PrecoComDesconto($desconto) {
        //variável local - acessa variável de classe e parâmetro
        $valorDescontado = $this->preco * (1 + $desconto / 100);
        return $valorDescontado < 10 ? 10 : $valorDescontado; //o valor não pode ser < 10
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Variable.php).