# Em PHP todas variáveis declaradas são globais?

Tags: php, variáveis, característica-linguagem, escopo-de-variáveis

Em C# existe o conceito de variáveis locais, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```cs
if (true) {
    int valor = 10;
}
else {
    valor = 5;
}

Console.Write(valor);
```

O código acima retornara um erro dizendo que a variável `valor` não existe no contexto atual:

> ```
> error CS0103: The name `valor' does not exist in the current context
> Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
> ```

Ou seja, a variável `valor` só existe dentro do `if`, e não é possível acessa-la fora do `if`.

Porem, em PHP não funciona da mesma forma que o C#, veja este exemplo:

```php
<?php
if (true) {
    $valor = 10;
}
else {
    $valor = 5;
}

echo 'Valor: ' . $valor;
```

A saída do script PHP acima será:

> Valor: 10

No entanto, é possível acessar a variável `valor`, mesmo ela não tendo sido declarada no mesmo contexto ou escopo, ela parece estar em algum tipo de escopo global, e isso me gerou as seguintes dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Todas as variáveis declaradas no PHP são globais?
2. Existe alguma forma de declarar variáveis locais no PHP?
3. Se todas variáveis for de escopo global o tempo de vida delas é de
   acordo com o tempo de vida do script?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php Na documentação do PHP é bem explicado.

Comment: @RafaelMafra seria interessante ter uma resposta aqui também afinal de contas acho que esta é a finalidade do SOpt, eu li a documentação, mas não entendi muitas coisas fiquei mais confuso ainda porque la trata como se tudo fosse local.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Todas as variáveis declaradas no PHP são globais?

Não, existe três tipos de escopos no PHP que são: condicional, de função e de classe (atributos, que funciona um pouco diferente). PHP por padrão tem um escopo mais flexível, ou seja, uma vez entrado no bloco de código, a variável ainda fica acessível. Um exemplo mais clássico é o foreach.

**Exemplo de definção condicional:**

```
if(false){
    $var = 'teste'; 
}else{

}
echo $var; //Notice: Undefined variable: var in
```

O mesmo serve para definição de funções:

```
if(false){
    function condicional(){
        echo 'função condicional chamada';
    }
}else{

}
condicional(); //undefined function condicional()
```

A chamada desse código retorna uma erro, troque o `false` por `true` e veja qual é o resultado agora.

**Exemplo de escopo flexível**

```
$arr = range(1,3);
foreach($arr as $item){
    echo $item .'<br>';
}
echo 'item ainda existe => '. $item * 2;
```

> Existe alguma forma de declarar variáveis locais no PHP?

Variáveis locais são conhecidas por pertencerem a uma função, elas não são acessíveis a outras funções ou parte de códigos.

Não existe uma forma tornar um escopo mais rígido, uma possibilidade é tonar a variável inacessível usando `unset()` após o uso.

> Se todas variáveis for de escopo global o tempo de vida delas é de acordo com o tempo de vida do script?

Não é exatamente global, uma vez definida a variável ela só será inutilizada/desalocada por um dos três escopos, manualmente e ao fim do script.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro, há um problema de terminologia aí. Variáveis globais tem [escopo e tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) por toda aplicação. O fato de estar dentro de uma função indica que ela é local. É assim em C#, PHP e diversas linguagens, mas não todas.

C# tem um escopo de blocos. Basta ter um bloco (esses que geralmente são compostos por chaves (a não ser que seja só uma linha, que pode omitir as chaves). PHP não tem, o escopo é de função. Mas isso não quer dizer que ela seja global.

Em geral isso não é um grande problema porque funções devem ser pequenas e é raro o escopo léxico (esse escopo "regional" dos blocos) ser tão útil assim. Eu imagino, mas não tenho certeza, que funções anônimas geram novo escopo. Se considerar que PHP é uma linguagem de *script*, o escopo de blocos deveria ser menos útil ainda.

Variáveis em PHP são guardadas em uma tabela de símbolos, grosso modo é como se tudo fosse em um grande *array* associativo, então é possível remover a variável em qualquer momento, mas não aconselho fazer isso. É só programar de forma mais ou menos organizada e não terá problemas.

Então explicitamente respondendo:

> Todas as variáveis declaradas no PHP são globais?

Não.

> Existe alguma forma de declarar variáveis locais no PHP?

Basta declarar dentro da função e ela será local.

> Se todas as variáveis forem de escopo global o tempo de vida delas é de acordo com o tempo de vida do *script*?

As realmente globais sim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode ter a impressão que a variável é global devido ao fato de poder acessá-la (ou pelo menos tentar acessá-la sem que isso resulte em um erro fatal) sem ter previamente definido-a.

Esse assunto é bem interessante e passível de muita reflexão.

Uma coisa realmente importante a qual deve-se prestar uma atenção especial é o seguinte: **Em qualquer linguagem de programação, TODA variável é, no mínimo, LOCAL.**

Normalmente não há pessoas falando isso dessa maneira, justamente por haver as terminologias LOCAL e GLOBAL. O que sugere que a variável ou é de um tipo ou é de outro, como se fossem antônimos. Mas analisando friamente a questão, verá que não é bem assim, LOCAL não é o contrário de GLOBAL. Esses nomes são  apenas características, e uma variável por ter as duas características.

Uma variável GLOBAL nada mais é do que uma variável LOCAL definida no escopo GLOBAL. Ou seja, ela ainda é LOCAL, mas com a característica extra de GLOBAL por fazer parte do escopo GLOBAL.

No PHP, os escopos sobrepõem as variáveis globais, o que é deveras curioso, mas isso ocorre devido à natureza dinâmica do PHP. Por isso existe uma SUPERGLOBAL chamada [$_GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.globals.php), a qual pode ser usada para acessar as variáveis globais em qualquer escopo.