# Laravel/Eloquent - Undefined variable: idPedido

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho duas queries buscando no model. A primeira delas está funcionando normalmente:

```
        $pedidos =  Pedido::
                orwhere(function($query){
                    $query->where('user_id', $_SESSION['idUsuario'])
                          ->where('status', 'Aberto');
                })
                ->get();
```

A segunda porém, está retornando erro de Undefined Variable: idPedido.

```
        $idUserPedido = $pedidos[0]['user_id'];
        $idPedido = $pedidos[0]['id'];

        $produtoDoPedido = PedidoProduto::orwhere(function($query){
            $query->where('id',$_SESSION['idUsuario'])
                  ->where('pedido_id', $idPedido);
        })
        ->get();
```

Quando dou echo na variável ela retorna o valor correto. O var_dump retorna um valor como sendo int.

Alguém sabe se há alguma restrição para utilizar variáveis no Eloquent?

Comment: Precisa 'importar' `$idPedido` para dentro da função anônima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variavél `$idPedido` está definida fora do escopo da sua query, a forma correta é usar assim:

```
$idUserPedido = $pedidos[0]['user_id'];
$idPedido = $pedidos[0]['id'];

$produtoDoPedido = PedidoProduto::orwhere(function($query) use($idPedido) {
            $query->where('id',$_SESSION['idUsuario'])
                  ->where('pedido_id', $idPedido);
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Precisa 'importar' `$idPedido` para dentro da função anônima. Assim como as nomeadas ambas possuem seu próprio escopo de variáveis. Isso é feito com palavra chave `use` na função:

```
PedidoProduto::orwhere(function($query) use($idPedido) {
```

Leitura recomenda:

[Manual - Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

[Em PHP todas variáveis declaradas são globais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173543/91)