# O que são tabelas fracas?

Tags: lua, referência

O que são *weak tables* (tabelas fracas) na versão 5.0 Lua? Quando usá-las?

Comment: este código está um pouco confuso e não faz o que você diz que faz. Se mostrar melhor a situação real talvez dê uma arrumar uma resposta.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade ele faz: `local l = 0; for k in next, tables do l = l + 1; end print(l);`. A situação real seria mais complicada de entender, pois é relacionada à instância de classes.

Comment: Só que nessa situação não ocorre o que você diz, então não tem que fazer nada, já está resolvido.

Comment: @bigown Não, a intenção é fazer as referências de chaves na tabela `tables` serem *fracas*, ou seja, serem ignoradas pelo coletor de lixo. Existe isso, só que quero uma resposta apropriada (mais ou menos wiki)

Comment: Depende das circunstâncias, sua pergunta não mostra o que deseja de fato, pra falar a verdade esse código está atrapalhando mais do que ajudando já que ele não tem nada a ver com a dúvida.

Comment: @bigown Ele é um caso onde referências fracas seriam úteis e ajudariam à resolver um problema de performance. Isso tem um pouco haver.

Comment: Seu código não tem referências então ele não tem nada a ver. Referências fracas nada tem a ver com performance. Na verdade se usar errado terá resultados desastrosos. Eu acho que você está bem perdido nesse assunto é melhor não usar o que não entende.

Comment: @bigown Ele tem sim referências, a própria tabela `tables` já usa uma referência. Essa chamada `init {}` é um atalho para `init({})`, ou seja, declara uma tabela para o primeiro argumento de `init`. Eu sei o que é referência, e sei que `init` também uma referência.

Comment: Tem uma referência. Essa não será destruída porque é global. Você fala em ter referências dentro de `tables`. A pergunta não faz sentido, mas vou responder o que dá para servir para outras pessoas saberem sobre referências fracas em termos genéricos.

Comment: @bigown Você está falando coisa nada haver, talvez você não leu o código direito.

Comment: Li, mas agora que postou uma resposta que fala exatamente o que eu respondi, percebi que já sabia o que queria como resposta, só não sabe como perguntar, o código da sua pergunta não precisa e não tem sentido usar o que você deseja como resposta. Se é possível, coloque um código na sua resposta que faça uso dentro desse código postado na pergunta (não outro).

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser dicutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5675/7210

Comment: Acho que isso não é lixo de memória olhando bem porque no for `for i = 1, 2e2 do` a expressão `2e2` é igual a 200. Converte `2e2` neste [site](http://www.convertworld.com/pt/numerais/) e vc vera que `2e2` é igual a 200 na base decimal. O `e` significa a quantidade de casas (0) após o numero.

Comment: @gato Não disse que nada era lixo de memória na pergunta. Estou falando que no exemplo há uma tabela com 200 campos que impedem 200 tabelas de serem coletados pelo lixo da linguagem. E eu sei que `2e2` ou `2e+2` é `200`.

Comment: @TheProHands veja se esses links de ajuda: [link 1](http://luatut.com/collectgarbage.html), [link 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_garbage_collection.htm) e [link 3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O que deseja fazer não precisa de referência fraca. Se o código é isso mesmo, vai executar algo e encerrar, não precisa fazer nada para a memória ser liberada.

Se pretende criar a tabela e que ela seja destruída logo em seguida, coloque em uma variável local. Mesmo que tenha que passar de uma função para outra faça com variáveis locais. Quando nenhuma variável estiver acessando a tabela ela poderá ser destruída. Variáveis locais cuidam invalidam a referência imediatamente o o GC coletará o objeto na próxima passada.

Usando referência fraca você não tem controle sobre o conteúdo, na primeira coleta poderá não existir mais os dados e se tentar acessar terá problemas, então usar referência fraca aí é um erro.

Para usar algo global e ter controle sobre o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) precisa fazer manualmente.

Uma resposta genérica conforme a [documentação](https://www.lua.org/pil/17.html), mas lembre-se que isso só deve ser usado quando pode ficar sem os dados a qualquer momento, até mesmo antes de usá-los.

```
a = {}
b = {}
setmetatable(a, b)
b.__mode = "v"
tabela = {}
a[1] = tabela
tabela = {}
a[2] = tabela
collectgarbage()
for k, v in pairs(a) do print(v) end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/rHXYDv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ktavfosq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/WeakReferences.lua).

O modo `v` atribuído com `setmetatable` torna os valores da tabela como referências fracas que é o que deseja. A letra `k` faz o mesmo com as chaves.

Comment: Agora só dá para dar +1 quando a resposta for editada.