# Por que a variável 'dados' não está definida?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

Código:

```
arquivo = open("surfing_data.csv")
id_de_verificação = int(input("Insira a ID do surfista desejado: "))

def pesquisa_de_surfista(pesquisa):
    dados = {}
    for linha in arquivo:
        (ID, nome, pais, média, prancha, idade) = linha.split(";")
        dados[ID] = (nome, pais, média, prancha, idade)
        print(ID)
        if pesquisa == ID:
            arquivo.close()
sufista = pesquisa_de_surfista(id_de_verificação)

if sufista:
    print("ID:          " + sufer['id'])
    print("Nome:        " + sufer['nome'])
    print("Pais:        " + sufer['pais'])
    print("Média:       " + sufer['média'])
    print("Prancha:     " + sufer['prancha'])
    print("Idade:       " + sufer['idade'])
print(dados)
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "identificação de surfistas.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(dados)
NameError: name 'dados' is not defined
```

Comment: Você editou a pergunta, mudou o contexto dela e acabou de invalidar as respostas que foram dadas. Por favor, reverta a edição abra outra pergunta com a nova dúvida.

Comment: por que esta dentro da função, e variaveis dentro da função não são acessadas fora dela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linha 22 é esta:

```
print(dados)
```

Vamos organizar o código e colocar comentários para facilitar o entendimento:

```
#Aqui é apenas um função, ela só será executada se for explicitamente chamada pelo código

def pesquisa_de_surfista(pesquisa):
    dados = {}
    for linha in arquivo:
        (ID, nome, pais, média, prancha, idade) = linha.split(";")
        dados[ID] = (nome, pais, média, prancha, idade)
        print(ID)
        if pesquisa == ID:
            arquivo.close()

#Aqui começa efetivamente o código a ser executado, a função terminou

arquivo = open("surfing_data.csv")
id_de_verificação = int(input("Insira a ID do surfista desejado: "))

sufista = pesquisa_de_surfista(id_de_verificação)    
if sufista:
    print("ID:          " + sufer['id'])
    print("Nome:        " + sufer['nome'])
    print("Pais:        " + sufer['pais'])
    print("Média:       " + sufer['média'])
    print("Prancha:     " + sufer['prancha'])
    print("Idade:       " + sufer['idade'])
print(dados)
```

A função `pesquisa_de_surfista` é totalmente separada do resto do código. O que está lá dentro não existe fora.

Então `dados` na linha 22 não existe mesmo. Isto é chamado de [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Ela existe dentro da função. Se deseja passar os dados de dentro da função para fora deve retornar alguma coisa.

Provavelmente a solução seria:

```
def pesquisa_de_surfista(pesquisa):
    dados = {}
    for linha in arquivo:
        (ID, nome, pais, média, prancha, idade) = linha.split(";")
        dados[ID] = (nome, pais, média, prancha, idade)
        print(ID)
        if pesquisa == ID:
            arquivo.close()
    return dados

arquivo = open("surfing_data.csv")
id_de_verificação = int(input("Insira a ID do surfista desejado: "))

sufista = pesquisa_de_surfista(id_de_verificação)    
if sufista:
    print("ID:          " + sufer['id'])
    print("Nome:        " + sufer['nome'])
    print("Pais:        " + sufer['pais'])
    print("Média:       " + sufer['média'])
    print("Prancha:     " + sufer['prancha'])
    print("Idade:       " + sufer['idade'])
print(sufista)
```

O código provavelmente tem outros erros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Scope.py).