# Quando eu crio uma função em C++ as variáveis dentro dela ficam na memória?

Tags: c++, memória, random, escopo-de-variáveis, números-aleatórios

Quando eu estudava pseudocódigo, eu aprendi que quando você chama uma função e cria uma variável, ela só "existe" quando eu chamo aquela função, por exemplo.

```
funcao teste():
      x = 10
      retorna x
```

No caso, quando eu chamasse a minha função teste, ele criaria a variável `x`, e depois que ela retornasse ele apagaria.

Eu estou estudando C++ e tentei fazer essa função pra gerar números aleatórios.

```
int gerar_numeros() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int x = rand() % 100;

    return x;
}
```

e para atribuir no vetor esse trecho na função `main()`.

```
for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++)
    {
        vetor[c] = gerar_numeros();
    }
```

Mas o problema é que ele só mudava os números quando eu rodava o *script* de novo, por exemplo, na primeira vez o todos os valores do vetor era 5, na segunda vez 10 e assim vai, aí eu mudei a lógica pra essa e deu certo.

```
void gerar_numeros(int vetor[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    //int x = 1 + rand() % 100;

    for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++)
    {
        vetor[c] = rand() % 100;
    }
```

Naquela lógica de cima é como se a variável `x` ficasse guardada na memória, e por isso sempre retorna o mesmo número.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um conceito mais abstrato. Ela é algo que ajuda você entender a memorização de dados no seu código. O que vai efetivamente na memória não é a variável. No código através dela você acessa uma posição de memória onde está o dado. Quando está usando a variável não existe, só um endereço.

O que você deve estar falando é [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) de variável.

A primeira função de falto cria uma posição de memória que será acessada pelo seu código com o nome de `x` e lá terá o valor 10, logo em seguida este valor é **copiado** para outra área por causa do `return` e o valor original é descartado no fim da função.

No segundo código nenhuma variável é necessária, basta retornar o que deseja. Mas se vai chamá-la mais de uma vez não pode chamar o `srand()` nela, esta função inicializa o gerador de números aleatórios, então todas as vezes está indo para o começo da lista.

Um problema não tem nada com o outro. Não é problema de escopo da variável.

Você tentou uma solução aleatória (não resisti) e obteve uma solução para o problema, mas provavelmente não da forma mais adequada.

Desde que já tenha inicializado a semente de aleatórios pode só fazer isto:

```
int gerar_numeros() { return rand() % 100; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/Range100.cpp).

Note que os números não são exatamente aleatórios, é o chamado pseudoaleatório. Serve para muita coisa, mas não para tudo. Inclusive o C++ já tem solução melhor que do C, que foi a usada.

Comment: Entendi, o problema é que eu estava iniciando o srand() toda vez que eu chamava a função certo? Obrigado!!

Comment: @zaque Sim `srand` define o ponto de inicio de geração dos aleatórios. Se define sempre o mesmo ponto de inicio antes de gerar um numero então gera sempre o mesmo numero.

Comment: Para ser mais completo, o problema não é tanto que chamou `srand()` varias vezes, porque está dando uma semente de `time(NULL)`, que muda. O problema é que chamou `srand()` varias vezes **muito rapido**. O código está completando antes que `time(NULL)` muda de valor. Se executar o código original para gerar muito mais números (talvez 100000), vai resultar em muitos números do mesmo valor seguido por muitos números de outro valor.