# Para que serve { } dentro da main()?

Tags: c, c++, design-pattern, sintaxe

Me deparei com uma situação em C que eu não conheço e nunca havia visto alguém utilizar antes. Dentro do método `main()` há várias chaves, acredito que para isolar o código porém existe uma mesma variável que em cada bloco de código recebe um valor e até muda de tipo. A variável `cfg` aparece diversas vezes, ora tendo o tipo `pjsua_config`, ora tendo o tipo `pjsua_transport_config`, ora tendo o tipo `pjsua_acc_config`.

[O trecho de código foi retirado do tutorial que ensina a usar a biblioteca pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm), a biblioteca é em C, isso seria alguma forma de simular uma herança (fazendo uma especie de *cast*)? Ou a cada bloco ele cria uma nova variável e destrói a anterior?

Confesso que estou meio perdido, pois estou tentando passar algumas coisas para C++, mas tive dificuldade para entender essa parte.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pjsua_acc_id acc_id;
    pj_status_t status;


    status = pjsua_create();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_create()", status);

    if (argc > 1) {
        status = pjsua_verify_url(argv[1]);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Invalid URL in argv", status);
    }

    /* Init pjsua */
    {
         pjsua_config cfg;
         pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;

         pjsua_config_default(&cfg);
         cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
         cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
         cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;

         pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
         log_cfg.console_level = 4;

         status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, NULL);
         if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_init()", status);
    }

    /* Add UDP transport. */
    {
         pjsua_transport_config cfg;

         pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
         cfg.port = 5060;
         status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
         if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
    }

    /* Initialization is done, now start pjsua */
    status = pjsua_start();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error starting pjsua", status);

    /* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */
    {
         pjsua_acc_config cfg;

         pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);
         cfg.id = pj_str("sip:" SIP_USER "@" SIP_DOMAIN);
         cfg.reg_uri = pj_str("sip:" SIP_DOMAIN);
         cfg.cred_count = 1;
         cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str(SIP_DOMAIN);
         cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
         cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(SIP_USER);
         cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
         cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(SIP_PASSWD);

         status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
         if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account", status);
    }

    /* If URL is specified, make call to the URL. */
    if (argc > 1) {
         pj_str_t uri = pj_str(argv[1]);
         status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &uri, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
         if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error making call", status);
    }

    /* Wait until user press "q" to quit. */
    for (;;) {
         char option[10];
         puts("Press 'h' to hangup all calls, 'q' to quit");
         if (fgets(option, sizeof(option), stdin) == NULL) {
             puts("EOF while reading stdin, will quit now..");
             break;
         }

         if (option[0] == 'q')
             break;

         if (option[0] == 'h')
             pjsua_call_hangup_all();
    }

    /* Destroy pjsua */
    pjsua_destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: é usado apenas para limitar o escopo, em cada escopo cfg é criado e ao fechar o escopo ela morre, e em outro escopo ela é "recriada" com outro tipo (não são as mesmas variaveis, só tem o mesmo nome)

Comment: As chaves delimitam escopos. Quando você faz isso, variáveis definidas lá dentro do escopo somente existem lá. Você pode então definir uma variável com mesmo nome várias vezes, até de tipos diferentes, sem ambiguidade se estiverem em escopos distintos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade, ele não tem nada demais, ele é igual ao que você sempre usou. Ele apenas demarca o início e fim de um bloco de instruções de código que devem ser considerados de uma forma única por algum motivo.

Um problema que vejo muito é que as pessoas não entendem o que usam, daí a frase que criei:

> Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar.

Neste caso específico foi usado para manter certas variáveis dentro de um escopo específico porque o bloco sempre gera um novo escopo. Então todas as variáveis que foram criadas dentro dele não existirão fora dele, e se existirem variáveis fora dele com o mesmo nome, não há confusão.

Então no `/* Init pjsua */` a variável `cfg`, por exemplo, não é a mesma variável `cfg` de `/* Add UDP transport. */` ou de `/* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */`. Mesmo nome, mas objetos diferentes.

Aprenda mais sobre [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Não é diferente de outros usos como na função, no `if`, no `for`, etc. Você só não sabia que ele era algo que existia por si só.

Em quase todas as situações é demonstração de algo errado no código e não costuma ser necessário. Se usa isto deveria rever o código, quem sabe separar partes em outra função.

Minha torcida é que agora comece olhar tudo no código como outros olhos e procure aprender como as coisas realmente são e não como elas parecem ser. Todos programariam melhor se fizessem isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Na verdade, instrução composta é mais ou menos comum. Como RAII é um grande idioma em C++, delimitar o tempo de vida de um estado é feito com esses escopos livres.

Comment: Em código linguição, sim.

Comment: @Maniero não uso, inclusive por esse motivo vim perguntar o que era, o código como postado na pergunta é um exemplo do próprio desenvolvedor da biblioteca. Concordo que é melhor separar em outros métodos. Mas obrigado, por tirar a dúvida. Concordo com a sua frase quando o código é seu, do contrário você pode saber programar, mas não ter domínio da sintaxe de uma linguagem específica. Afinal elaborar uma receita de bolo, também é visto por muitos como uma forma de programação.

Comment: @SilenoBrito Se você não usa você não programa em C, n]ao dá nem pra fazer Hello World sem isso. Sem domínio do que está fazendo em qualquer coisa, a pessoa não sabe fazer aquilo, ela está se enganando que sabe. E eu sei que algumas pessoas consideram que receita de bolo é programar, essas pessoas são as que não sabem programar..

Answer (score 1):

Não tem funcionalidade programática além de separar os escopos (poder declarar variáveis de mesmo nome com tipos diferentes) e provavelmente o autor utilizou para organizar o código no editor/IDE que estava utilizando. Como existe o `#region` em c#.

Comment: Não é como se fosse o `#region` e não foi usado só para organizar o código, neste caso feito sem o bloco daria erro.

Comment: Eu disse provavelmente, pois na maioria das IDE's dá pra "comprimir" esses blocos e manter os comentários no início do bloco.