# Como usar o do while em javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso de usar o `do` e o `while` no javascript, mas nunca o fiz e estou com algumas dúvidas.

Estou a usar desta forma:

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('./alertas', function (data) {

 var linha = ``;
 var nomede = '';
 var i = 0;

do {
        if(nomede != Data){
       linha += `<tr>      
       <td>${ Data }</td>       
       </tr>`
       }
    }
    while(i < data){
       Id = data[i][0];
       De = data[i][1];
       Assunto = data[i][2];
       Conteudo = data[i][3];
       Prioridade = data[i][4];
       Hora = data[i][5];
       Data = data[i][6];

       linha += `<tr >           
       <td>${ De }</td> 
       <td>${ Assunto }</td>
       <td>${ Prioridade }</td> 
       <td>${ Hora }</td> 
       </tr>`; 
    }
    $("#alerta tbody").html(linha);
}); 
});
```

Mas retorna este erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Data is not defined at Object.success

Estou a usar o `do` e o `while` para escrever uma tabela dinâmica e ao mesmo tempo colocar uma separação por data das linhas retornadas.

Exemplo:

```
De  Assunto Prioridade  Recebido
Data: 2020-07-20
1 linha
2 linha 
3 linha
4 linha
Data: 2020-07-24
5 linha
6 linha 
7 linha
8 linha
```

e assim sucessivamente

Comment: Já não sei como colocar as perguntas para não ter votos negativos. Tento explicar da melhor forma o meu problema, mas é sempre mal recebido

Comment: A sintaxe correta é `do { faz algo } while (condição);` mas vc fez `do { faz algo } while (condição) { faz outra coisa }`, que eu nem sei se é válido (e se for, provavelmente não faz o que vc precisa). Enfim, use apenas  `do { faz algo } while (condição);` ou apenas `while (condição) { faz algo }` - a diferença entre eles já foi explicada na resposta abaixo

Comment: @hkotsubo podemos falar no chat?

Comment: Infelizmente não vou poder, já "encerrei" por hoje (desliguei o computador, só acessei o site pelo celular pra ver se tinha alguma novidade, mas em breve ficarei offline e só volto amanhã) :-) Mas aproveitando, vi que essa sintaxe não dá erro, mas não faz bem o que vc quer: https://ideone.com/b1gbus - eu tb sugiro que vc edite a pergunta e coloque um exemplo de como está esse array `data`, pois se for da forma que imagino, provavelmente tem outra forma de resolver (mas é só especulação, tendo um exemplo dos dados dá pra ter uma ideia melhor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma que você está usando [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) está errada. A sintaxe é apenas:

```
do {
    faz algo
} while (condição);
```

Mas você fez:

```
do {
    faz algo
} while (condição) {
    faz outra coisa
}
```

Porém, esse bloco depois do `while` não faz mais parte do *loop*. Ex:

```js
var i = 0;
do {
  console.log('dentro', i);
  i++;
  if (i > 2)
    break;
} while (i < 10) {
  console.log('depois', i);
}
```

A saída é:

```
dentro 0
dentro 1
dentro 2
depois 3
```

Ou seja, o que está dentro do `do...while` é executado várias vezes, e o que está depois do `while`, somente uma vez. Mesmo que a condição do `while` ainda seja verdade (pois é feito o `break` quando `i` vale `3`, então a condição `i < 10` ainda é verdadeira), o *loop* é tudo que está dentro de `do { } while`.

O que vem depois é na verdade um [bloco de código "isolado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323998/112052), que não faz parte do `do...while`.
O problema é que no JavaScript o ponto-e-vírgula no final de *statements* é opcional (veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596), [aqui](/q/432960/112052)  e [aqui](/q/3341/112052)), então isso:

```
do {
    abc
} while (condição) {
    xyz
}
```

É o mesmo que isso:

```
do {
    abc
} while (condição); // ponto-e-vírgula, indica que o do...while terminou

{ // chaves indica o início de um bloco de código
    xyz
}
```

Você mesmo pode testar isso [neste site](http://jsutility.pjoneil.net/) (na aba "Format" é possível ver onde o ponto-e-vírgula é inserido).

---

Enfim, talvez você nem precise de um bloco `do...while`, pois tem formas melhores de se iterar por um array (sem contar que você está comparando `i < data`, ou seja, um número com um array, e também não está incrementando o `i` em nenhum lugar).

Não ficou claro o conteúdo de `data`, mas **assumindo que os elementos estão ordenados por data**, uma forma de obter a saída que você quer seria:

```
let currentDate = null;
for (const d of data) {
    let [id, de, assunto, conteudo, prioridade, hora, date] = d;
    if (currentDate != date) {
        linha += `<tr><td>${date}</td></tr>`;
        currentDate = date;
    }
    linha += `<tr>
        <td>${de}</td> 
       <td>${assunto}</td>
       <td>${prioridade}</td> 
       <td>${hora}</td> 
       </tr>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você precisa inicialmente reler o seu próprio código e procurar erros que são óbvios, por exemplo:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Data is not defined at Object.success

Este erro está te dizendo que `Data` não existe, não foi declarada nem inicializada em nenhuma parte do teu código, talvez você quisesse usar `data` que é o nome da variável que você definiu aqui `$.getJSON('./alertas', function (data)`, variáveis com letras maiúsculas e minusculas são diferentes.

Claramente poderá te ajudar também uma pequena leitura sobre o construto [do/while](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp), basicamente é igual ao `while` normal, exceto por uma coisa, o seu código sempre será executado ao menos 1 vez. Exemplo:

```js
let i = 4;
while(i < 3){
  console.log(i++);
}
```

Basicamente no código acima, se a variável `i` tiver um valor superior ou igual a 3, o código não será executado, isto porque o controle da condição é feito antes da execução. O que acontece quando você usa o `do/while` é que primeiro ele irá executar 1x o código e só então controlar a condição desejada, exemplo:

```js
let i = 4;
do{
  console.log(i++);
}while(i < 3);
```

Comment: obrigado pelo esclarecimento.