# Variavel nos loops e funcao em C

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

As variaveis na função e nos loops nao se mantem? Porque eu achava que se mantinha no loop, diferente da função que é esquecida

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x = 0;
int main(){
int i, x = 1;
printf("%d\n", x);
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    int x = 2;
    printf("%d/ ", x);
{
    int x = 3;
    printf("%d/ ", x);
}}
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

Comment: *"eu achava que se mantinha no loop, diferente da função que é esquecida"* explique melhor isso. Tem alguns conceitos envolvidos aqui, como por exemplo se a variável é local, ponteiro, etc.

Comment: esse código também usar duas variáveis "x", uma de escopo global e outra dentro do método `main`, pq não usar outro nome dentro do loop em main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, antes de mais nada, faça um favor a si mesmo e formate corretamente seu código:

```
int main() {
    int i, x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int x = 2;
        printf("%d/ ", x);
        {
            int x = 3;
            printf("%d/ ", x);
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

Pronto, assim fica mais fácil ver quais são as partes do código, como ele está organizado e o que está dentro do que. E a chave para entender o que acontece é esse trecho específico:

```
{
    int x = 3;
    printf("%d/ ", x);
}
```

Cada vez que você abre chaves (com o caractere `{`), está criando um novo bloco, e [conforme explicado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323998/112052), cada bloco gera um novo [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/112052). Isso quer dizer que qualquer variável criada ali dentro só existe naquele bloco. Mesmo que ela tenha o mesmo nome de outra variável criada fora dele, não importa: apesar de terem o mesmo nome, são variáveis diferentes.

Veja por exemplo este código:

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printf("Antes do bloco: %d\n", n);
    { // início do bloco
        int n = 1;
        printf("Dentro do bloco, novo n: %d\n", n);
        n = 2;
        printf("Dentro do bloco, mudando valor do n: %d\n", n);
    } // fim do bloco
    printf("Depois do bloco: %d\n", n);
    n = 3;
    printf("Depois do bloco, mudando valor do n: %d\n", n);
}
```

A saída dele é:

```
Antes do bloco: 0
Dentro do bloco, novo n: 1
Dentro do bloco, mudando valor do n: 2
Depois do bloco: 0
Depois do bloco, mudando valor do n: 3
```

Ou seja, fora do bloco, o que vale é o `n` criado na primeira linha do `main` (no caso, o `int n = 0`).

Dentro do bloco eu crio um novo `n` (na linha `int n = 1`), e como ele foi criado dentro do bloco, ele só existe dentro desse bloco, e não é o mesmo `n` que foi criado fora dele (apesar de terem o mesmo nome, são variáveis diferentes).

Depois que o bloco termina, o `n` "interno" (o que "pertence" ao bloco) deixa de existir e volta a "valer" o `n` "externo" (o que foi criado no início do `main`).

---

No seu caso, tem mais de um bloco: o `for` cria um novo escopo, e dentro do `for` tem outro bloco que cria outro escopo:

```
int main() {
    int i, x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x); // esse é o x que foi criado na linha de cima
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int x = 2; // esse x vale para o escopo do for
        printf("%d/ ", x);
        { // início do bloco
            int x = 3; // esse x vale para o bloco iniciado na linha anterior
            printf("%d/ ", x);
        } // fim do bloco
    }
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

Ou seja, além do `x` criado no início do `main` (o `x = 1`), ainda temos o que é criado dentro do `for` (o `int x = 2`) e mais um que é criado no bloco que está dentro do `for` (o `int x = 3`). Apesar de terem o mesmo nome, não são a mesma variável, pois cada uma tem seu próprio escopo.

Comment: muito bom, hkotsubo mas por que quando declaramos uma variável na função main e ai colocamos ela num laço for, a variável é reconhecida? Caso a variável nao seja declarada na main precisamos declarar dentro do laço

Comment: @Cl2727 Não sei se entendi bem a dúvida, mas enfim: se vc declara uma variável no `main`, ela fica visível em qualquer lugar dentro do `main` (não importa se está dentro de um `if`, `for`, o que for). Enfim, sugiro que estude sobre o escopo de variáveis em C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope