# Ao inserir em um vetor sempre sobrepõe o valor anteriormente inserido

Tags: c, array, variáveis

No meu código ao adicionar um contato (X), e ver a lista de contatos, eu tenho contato X, porem ao adicionar outro contato (Y), e ir ver a lista, o contato Y substitui o X, como posso fazer pra adicionar vários no vetor?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
/*--------------------------------------ESTRUTURA DA AGENDA------------------------------------------------------*/
 struct Pessoa {
    char nome[100], email [100], rua[100], bairro[100], cidade[100], estado[100], pais[100], numero[4], complemento[10], cep[8], telefone[30], observacao[200];
    int dia, mes, ano;
} Agenda[5]; /* VETOR AGENDA PARA 3 PESSOAS POR QUESTÕES DE SIMPLIFICAÇÃO. OS OUTROS 2 ESPAÇOS SÃO PARA O AUX. */

/*--------------------------------FUNÇÕES (SÃO CHAMADAS PELO MENU)----------------------------------------------*/
void BuscarNome (void);
void BuscarMes (void);
void BuscarMesDia (void);
void InserirContato (void);
void RemoverContato (void);
void AgendaCompleta (void);
int NomeNulo(char *s);

main() {
    int i,j,result, cont=1;
    char escolha;
    /* --------MENU PRINCIPAL DE OPÇÕES----------*/
    menu: 
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("*******************AGENDA PESSOAL*******************\n");
    printf ("*                                                  *\n");
    printf ("*  [1] Buscar contato por nome.                    *\n");
    printf ("*  [2] Buscar contato por mes de aniversario.      *\n");
    printf ("*  [3] Buscar contato por mes e dia de aniversario.*\n");
    printf ("*  [4] Adicionar um contato a agenda.              *\n");
    printf ("*  [5] Remover um contato da agenda.               *\n");
    printf ("*  [6] Mostrar todos os contatos registrados.      *\n");
    printf ("*                                                  *\n");
    printf ("****************************************************\n");

    printf ("Escolha uma opcao: "); scanf("%d", &escolha);

    switch (escolha) {
        case 1 :
            system ("cls");
            BuscarNome();
            goto menu;
            break;

        case 2 :
            system ("cls");
            BuscarMes();
            goto menu;
            break;

        case 3 :
            system ("cls");
            BuscarMesDia();
            goto menu;
            break;

        case 4 :
            system ("cls");
            InserirContato();
            sleep (2);
            system ("cls");
            goto menu;
            break;

        case 5 :
            system ("cls");
            RemoverContato();
            goto menu;
            break;

        case 6 :
            system ("cls");
            AgendaCompleta();


            goto menu;
            break;

        default :
            system ("cls");
            printf ("\n");
            printf ("               Digite uma opcao valida\n");
            sleep (2);
            goto menu;
            break;

    }

    system("pause");
}

void BuscarNome () {
    printf ("Vc buscou um contato pelo nome!");
}

void BuscarMes () {
    printf ("Vc buscou um contato pelo mes de aniversario!");
} 

void BuscarMesDia () {
    printf ("Vc buscou um contato pelo mes e dia de aniversario!");
} 

void InserirContato () {
    int cont=1;
    printf ("Adicionar um contato:\n");
    printf ("Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &Agenda[cont].nome); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Telefone: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].telefone); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Email: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].email); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Aniversario [DIA]: ");
    scanf("%d", &Agenda[cont].dia); fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Aniversario [MES]: ");
    scanf("%d", &Agenda[cont].mes); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Aniversario [ANO]: ");
    scanf("%d", &Agenda[cont].ano); fflush(stdin); 
/*  printf ("Endereco: \n");
    printf ("Rua: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].rua); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Bairro: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].bairro); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Cidade: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].cidade); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Estado: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].estado); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Pais: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].pais); fflush(stdin); 
    printf ("Numero: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].numero); fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Complemento: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].complemento); fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Cep: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].cep); fflush(stdin); */
    printf ("Observacao: ");
    gets(Agenda[cont].observacao); fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Contato inserido na agenda!!");
    cont++;
} 

void RemoverContato () {
    printf ("Vc removeu um contato!");
} 

void AgendaCompleta () {
    int i, opcao;
    contatos:
    printf ("*******************CONTATOS*************************\n");
    printf ("*                                                  *\n");
    printf ("*  [1] Nome, Telefone e Email.                     *\n");
    printf ("*  [2] Todos os dados dos contatos.                *\n"); 
    printf ("*                                                  *\n");
    printf ("****************************************************\n");

    printf ("Escolha uma opcao: "); scanf("%d", &opcao);
    switch (opcao) {
        case 1:
            system ("cls");
            for(i=0;i<5;i++) { 
                if(!NomeNulo(Agenda[i].nome)) { // SO MOSTRA OS CONTATOS Q TIVEREM NOME
                    printf ("Contato[%d]\n", i);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n",Agenda[i].nome);
                    printf("Telefone: %s\n",Agenda[i].telefone);
                    printf("Email: %s\n",Agenda[i].email);
                    printf("\n"); 
                    }
                }
            break;

        case 2: 
            system ("cls");
            for(i=0;i<5;i++) { 
                if(!NomeNulo(Agenda[i].nome)) { // SO MOSTRA OS CONTATOS Q TIVEREM NOME
                    printf ("Contato[%d]\n", i);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n",Agenda[i].nome);
                    printf("Endereco: %s",Agenda[i].rua);
                    printf(", %s",Agenda[i].bairro);
                    printf(", %s",Agenda[i].cidade);
                    printf(", %s",Agenda[i].estado);
                    printf(", %s\n",Agenda[i].pais);
                    printf("Numero: %s\n",Agenda[i].numero);
                    printf("Complemento: %s\n",Agenda[i].complemento);
                    printf("CEP: %s\n",Agenda[i].cep);
                    printf("Telefone: %s\n",Agenda[i].telefone);
                    printf("Email: %s\n",Agenda[i].email);
                    printf("Data de aniversario: %d/%d/%d\n",Agenda[i].dia, Agenda[i].mes, Agenda[i].ano);
                    printf("Observacao: %s\n",Agenda[i].observacao);
                    printf("\n"); 
                }
            }
            break;

            default :
                system ("cls");
                printf ("\n");
                printf ("           Digite uma opcao valida\n");
                sleep (2);
                goto contatos;
                break;  
    }
}

int NomeNulo(char *s){
    return(s[0] == '\0');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa está inserindo o contato na posição cont do vetor, que tem o valor fixo de 1, então ele sempre vai adicionar o registro na mesma posição do vetor. É necessário utilizar um laço de repetição para incrementar a variável cont e evitar que o registro seja salvo sempre na mesma posição.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal nesses casos é fazer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pra gente não ter que ler todo seu código, interpretá-lo, depurá-lo, testá-lo, etc. Mas grosso modo o problema é que está sempre entrando na função de inserção e iniciando a posição inicial em 1, então sempre será lá que será inserido, o que está adicionando nada vale. E no final da função deve retornar o valor novo para a `main()`. Precisa aprender sobre [escopo de variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Precisaria ter um controle que partisse da função `main()` e a posição seria passada como argumento na chamada da função que teria um parâmetro apropriado para recebê-lo. Na verdade o próprio *array* `agenda` deveria ser criado dentro da `main()` e ser passado como argumento também. Tudo isto é errado em códigos reais, mas para exercício pode ser feito. Ainda estará aprendendo o jeito errado real, mas pelo menos não será errado até para um exercício.

Tem diversos outros erros neste código, inclusive redundância e não deveria usar `goto`, prefira um `while`.