# Diferença de uso de objeto imutável em argumento de método ou fora dele

Tags: java, string, variáveis, instanciar-objeto

Se eu tenho a seguinte `String` cuja mesma foi criada:

```
String s1 = "Primeira String";
```

Ao usar o método:

```
s1.toUpperCase();
```

nada acontece porque neste momento foi criada uma instância e não foi atribuída a nenhuma variável.

Mas se eu rodar:

```
System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase());
```

eu vejo o resultado em maiúsculo, qual é a diferença destes casos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença é só que um você não vê e a outra você vê, nada mais. A diferença é o método `println()`.

> nada acontece

Premissa errada.

> neste momento foi criada uma instância

Contradiz a premissa.

O primeiro cria a instância nova e nada mais pode se fazer com aquilo. Teve custo para criar, ocupou memória e ficará lá até o objeto ser coletado. O segundo código passa esse objeto através de uma referência para o método `println()` fazer o que ele sabe fazer, então potencialmente terá um [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) garantido um pouco maior, mas na prática sabemos que isso não importa em um exemplo simples, o objeto só estará disponível por um instante na sua criação e execução do método.

Na verdade o problema em si nada tem a ver com o fato do objeto ser imutável, isso é circunstancial, qualquer objeto que fosse criado ocorreria o mesmo.

Talvez falte entendimento do que é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), ela é mais simples do que as pessoas imaginam.

Comment: A sua primeira fase esclareceu pra mim rsrs, obrigado.