# Como que eu tiro valores de variáveis de dentro de uma função?

Tags: python, funções, variáveis

Eu tenho uma função, nome rodadas, com outra função dentro, e nesta função que ta dentro tenho uma variável declarada, ela chama `pecas_comp`, eu preciso dela na função rodadas mas não estou conseguindo entrar na função mais funda.

```
    def computador_escolhe_jogada (n, m):
if n <= m:
    pecas_comp = n
    n = 0
else:
    a = 1 
    while a < m:
        resto = n - a
        if resto % (m + 1) == 0:
            n = n - a
            pecas_comp = a
            a = m
        else:
            a = a + 1
return (n, pecas_comp)


def rodadas(n, m):
   while n > 0:
       computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
       print("O computador tirou ", pecas_comp, "peças.")
       print("Agora restam ", n, "peças no tabuleiro.")
       comeca = 1
```

Comment: Oi João tudo bom, por favor coloca o código que fez para que possamos entender o que ja foi feito e ajudar a explicar como chegar na solução que deseja.

Comment: Amigo, meu código esta com 60 linhas, pois não são só essas duas funções, porem, esta tudo interligado. Tem algum problema eu colocar tudo?

Comment: Não tem problema colocar tudo não, mas caso tenha uma forma de ser mais objetivo fazendo um exemplo simplificado do problema, ajuda ainda mais para que possamos entender.

Comment: @João seria só você isolar estas duas funções.

Comment: okay, vou editar e ja coloco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não garanto que o código está correto, mas resolvi o problema retornando o valor que precisava. Tinha outros problemas. Note que sequer precisa de variável para o que estava querendo fazer. [Variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é superestimada.

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    if n <= m:
        pecas_comp = n
        n = 0
    else:
        a = 1 
        while a < m:
            resto = n - a
            if resto % (m + 1) == 0:
                n -= a
                pecas_comp = a
                a = m
            else:
                a += 1
    return pecas_comp

def rodadas(n, m):
    while n > 0:
        pecas_comp = computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
        print("O computador tirou ", pecas_comp, "peças.")
        print("Agora restam ", n, "peças no tabuleiro.")
    return 1 

def partida():
    n = int(input("Quantas peças?"))
    m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada?"))
    if n // (m + 1) == 0:
        print("Você começa")
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

rodadas(n, m)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ReturnData.py).

---

O que está escrito abaixo é só baseado na pergunta original que deu informações equivocadas do que o código realmente era, então fica por razões históricas e que sirva para outro problema.

> Como que eu faço para ter o valor dela?

O mais correto é retornar esse valor da função mais interna para a externa. Você pode até retornar um tupla se precisa retornar mais que um valor. Tem certeza que precisava que uma função estivesse dentro da outra? Alguma coisa me diz que não precisa.

O segundo meio mais correto é declara uma variável na função mais externa e usa-la na interna para receber o valor, como a variável foi criada na função que tem [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) maior, o valor sobreviverá mesmo no escopo da função mais externa.

> Se eu transformar em global dá certo?

Esta seria a pior solução, mas não deixa de ser uma. Sem uma boa justificativa eu não usaria assim.

> E uma vez que declaro a variável em global dentro de uma função tenho que declarar nas outras funções também?

Não é necessário, no momento que faz isto a variável é visível e tem tempo de vida por toda aplicação, só não faça isso, já percebeu o perigo que é em aplicação grande?

O uso de globais só deveriam ser último caso e só realizado por quem tem muita experiência. Para dar uma comparação é bem mais fácil isolar uma função do resto do problema e fazer um código que seja um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do que lidar direito com variáveis globais.

Comment: Então, eu to retornando ela, ate coloquei em tupla agora, mas ainda da erro, esta dizendo que o pecas_comp não está definida.

Comment: Agora que colocou o código ele nem está do jeito que você descreveu, e embora agora tenha mais informações, ficou tudo jogado sem um descrição clara. Mais ainda, o código é extramente confuso. Eu acho que você deveria começar por coisas mais básicas, está fazendo algo que não está conseguindo organizar porque está pulando etapas. Eu sequer entendi o fluxo aí, mas talvez só porque tem vários erros.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui terminar o programa, estava tendo dificuldades para entrar na função e retornar os valores, mas do jeito que você fez, colocando a função na variável deu certo. Eu estou fazendo um curso online pela USP e eles passaram esse exercício, também achei um pouco avançado, por mexer com funções e tals mas mesmo assim me dispus a tentar fazer e acredito que as dificuldades ajudam no processo de aprendizagem. Enfim, obrigado!