# Variável aparece como não declarada ao tentar usá-la no laço "do while"

Tags: c, variáveis, while, declaração-de-variável

Ao tentar criar um programa que converta Celsius em Fahrenheit para ir pegando prática e me deparo com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Erro "sair " undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Minha intenção como o `do while` era criar uma opção de saída para o usuário. O restante do código a princípio funciona como o esperado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    do
    {
        int sair;
        float temp,formula;
        puts("Graus Celsius:");
        scanf("%f",&temp);
        system("cls");


        formula = temp * 1.8 + 32;
        printf("\nCelsius:%.1f\n\nFahrenheit:%.1f\n\n",temp,formula);

        puts("Digite 1 para sair ou 2 para uma nova conversao...\n");
        scanf("%d", &sair);
    }
    while(sair == 1);
    {
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o `while` não está dentro do bloco entre chaves, ele está fora, então ele só enxerga variáveis que foram declaradas fora. Estude sobre [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Além disso tem um bloco após o `while` que não faz sentido, ainda que funcione como esperado.

Eu não gosto de variáveis que atual como *flags*, e esta variável `sair` acaba sendo uma quando declara fora. É sempre melhor manter variáveis no menor escopo possível. Este casos não faz muita diferença, mas em casos mais complexos pode ajudar ficar mais legível. Este caso a variável `sair` deveria ser só usada para guardar o valor e tomar uma decisão dentro do bloco, então é melhor declarar ali dentro mesmo, está certo, mas não pode usar o `while` como usou, então saia de forma explícita com um `if` mesmo (bons programadores são detalhistas e fazem sempre o mais simples):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        float temp;
        puts("Graus Celsius:");
        scanf("%f", &temp);
        printf("\nCelsius: %.1f\nFahrenheit: %.1f\n", temp, temp * 1.8 + 32);
        puts("Digite 1 para sair ou 2 para uma nova conversao...\n");
        int sair;
        scanf("%d", &sair);
        if (sair == 1) break;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hgixJg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LoopExit). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/LoopExit.c).

Comment: Por que não gosta de variáveis usadas como flag?

Comment: Evito estado, evito mutação de estado, evitado escopo maior que deveria em estado. *Flag* sempre é um estado evitável, então eu evito. Estado e sua mutação é a causa da maioria dos *bugs*. Em linguagens funcionais nem tem como ter *flags*. Flag parece gambiarra porque não conseguir dar a condição certa. Esse é um caso que não é das mais graves, mas ainda é feio ter que declarar a variável fora quando não precisa dela fora do bloco (pra mim é até erro da linguagem não aceitar assim). Tem quem acha que nem deveria existir o `do-while` e sempre ser assim como eu fiz, quando tem pelo menos 1 exec.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre o `while` "normal" e o `do while` é que no `do while` o laço sempre vai ser executado **pelo menos** uma vez.

Assim, as variáveis de teste tem de estarem declaradas antes do laço iniciar, do contrário ele não conseguirá fazer as verificações para executar este ciclo inicial, que é o seu problema.

O [seguinte flow](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop) ilustra bem o que acontece neste tipo de laço:

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver é só declarar o `sair` fora do laço.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int sair = 0;
    do
    {
        float temp,formula;
        puts("Graus Celsius:");
        scanf("%f",&temp);
        system("cls");


        formula = temp * 1.8 + 32;
        printf("\nCelsius:%.1f\n\nFahrenheit:%.1f\n\n",temp,formula);

        puts("Digite 1 para sair ou 2 para uma nova conversao...\n");
        scanf("%d", &sair);
    }
    while(sair == 1);
    {
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Eu também declarei o `sair` como `0`. Apenas para ficar mais inteligível o código