# Como voltar a execução de um programa em C sem loop e sem compilar novamente?

Tags: c, goto

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{ 
int Senha, Tentativa;
int Contador_De_Erros = 1;
printf("Vez do jogador 1 jogar\n\nLembrando que a senha tem que ser um numero entre 0 e 100\n\n");
printf("Qual sera a senha ? ");
scanf("%d",&Senha);
while (Senha < 0 || Senha > 100)
{
    printf("\nValor invalido, tente uma senha entre 0 e 100\n");
    printf("\nVez do jogador 1 jogar\n\nLembrando que a senha tem que ser um numero entre 0 e 100\n");
    printf("\nQual sera a senha ? ");
    scanf("%d",&Senha);
}
printf("\nVez do jogador 2 jogar\n\nQual a sua tentativa de advinhar o numero ? ");
scanf("%d",&Tentativa);
while (Tentativa < 0 || Tentativa > 100 )
{
    printf("\nValor invalido, tente uma tentativa entre 0 e 100\n");
    printf("\nVez do jogador 2 jogar\n\nQual a sua tentativa de advinhar o numero ? ");
    scanf("%d",&Tentativa);
} 
if (Tentativa == Senha - 1 || Tentativa == Senha + 1)
{
    printf("\nTa quente\n");
}
if (Tentativa < Senha && Tentativa != Senha - 1)
{
    printf("\nSua tentativa %d e menor que a senha, digite novamente a senha\n",Tentativa);
}
else if (Tentativa > Senha && Tentativa != Senha + 1)
{
    printf("\nSua tentativa %d e maior que a senha, digite novamente a senha\n",Tentativa);
}

while (Contador_De_Erros < 5 && Tentativa != Senha)
{   


    printf("\nVez do jogador 2 jogar\n\nQual a sua tentativa de advinhar o numero ? ");
    scanf("%d",&Tentativa);
    while (Tentativa < 0 || Tentativa > 100 )
    {
    printf("\nValor invalido, tente uma tentativa entre 0 e 100\n");
    printf("\nVez do jogador 2 jogar\n\nQual a sua tentativa de advinhar o numero ? ");
    scanf("%d",&Tentativa);
    }
    if (Tentativa == Senha - 1 || Tentativa == Senha + 1)
    {
        printf("\nTa quente\n");
    }
    if (Tentativa < Senha && Tentativa != Senha - 1)
    {
        printf("\nSua tentativa %d e menor que a senha, digite novamente a senha\n",Tentativa);
    }
    else if (Tentativa > Senha && Tentativa != Senha + 1)
    {
        printf("\nSua tentativa %d e maior que a senha, digite novamente a senha\n",Tentativa);
    }
    Contador_De_Erros += 1;
}
if (Tentativa == Senha)
{ 
    printf("\nVoce acertou ! o numero %d era a senha escolhida pelo jogador 1",Senha);
}
if (Tentativa != Senha)
{
    printf("\nVoce nao acertou a senha que era %d", Senha);
}

return 0;
}
int Volta_Tudo()
{
int Jogar_Novamente;
printf("Voce quer jogar novamente ?\n1 para SIM\n2 para Nao ");
scanf("%d",&Jogar_Novamente);
if (Jogar_Novamente == 1)
{
    goto main; 
}
return main;
}
```

Quero executar esse código novamente após o seu termino, há algum modo de fazê-lo sem *loop* e sem compilar ele novamente? Esse comando `goto` seria um bom método? Se sim, como tratar esse erro ao chamar nele a função `main`? Se não, qual a melhor maneira pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilar nada tem a ver com isso.

De fato esse `goto` é muito errado e nem compila (espero que não compile em algum compilador maluco, se compilar eu não o usaria mais), ele não faz o menor sentido. Mas importa pouco porque essa função sequer está sendo chamada então nesse código específico nem tem função fazer isso.

[O `goto` deve ser evitado sempre que possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) e nesse caso é possível. Pode nem ficar ótimo, mas esse é tão ruim que quase qualquer coisa é melhor que isso.

O código todo tem alguns problemas e foge do padrão como geralmente as pessoas programam. Pode funcionar, mas não é assim que se programa, cuidado para não aprender errado. Acho até que o problema está mal definido.

Tem algumas soluções possíveis e a mais fácil e óbvia na forma que começou escrever é colocar todo o código dentro de um laço, e você sabe fazer isso porque fez algumas vezes. É muito simples, quando precisa que algo seja repetido ele deve estar dentro de um laço, este mecanismo serve para isso.

Se fizer isso então é só controlar de alguma forma a saída do laço. Esse laço pode ser até mesmo um `while (1)` que é um laço infinito, aí dentro dele em algum lugar, em geral no final, você pergunta se quer continuar e dependendo da resposta terá um `if` para quebrar o laço (`break`) e então finalmente ir para o fim da execução. essa última parte você já fez, mas eu não faria em outra função.

Pode até fazer em outra função, mas isso faz pouco sentido ali porque várias coisas que deveria fazer em outra função no seu código não está, e também seria interessante fazer o simples primeiro. Quando dominar a repetição e controlar a saída dentro do laço pode sofisticar e abstrair isso para uma função. Não é tão difícil, mas o `if` terá que estar no laço (a não ser que controle direto no `while`, mas não gosto disso, em geral tem que aumentar escopo de variável para nenhum ganho importante, e costuma gerar algumas confusões).

O que não pode fazer é chamar a função `main()` novamente como alguns fazem. Em exercício funcionará, mas assim que a pessoa começar fazer códigos mais complexos ela provocará um [*stack overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101) em algum momento.

Eu dei [uma resposta que mostra como é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/399712/101).