# Alocação dinâmica no escopo errado

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Aloquei dinamicamente um vetor de estruturas com `qtdeFuncionarios` posições dentro de um `if`, mas agora preciso utilizá-lo dentro de outra estrutura condicional e o compilador acusa problema de escopo. Como proceder?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  char *nome;
  char *email;
  int idade;
} Funcionario;

int main() {
  while(1){
    int i, opcao, qtdeFuncionarios;

    printf("1.Cadastrar funcionario\n");
    printf("2.Listar funcionarios\n");
    printf("3.Editar dados de funcionario\n");
    printf("4.Excluir funcionario\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);
    if (opcao == 1) {        
        printf("Quantos funcionarios deseja cadastrar? ");
        scanf("%d", &qtdeFuncionarios);
        Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(qtdeFuncionarios * sizeof(Funcionario));
        for ( i = 0; i < qtdeFuncionarios; i++) {  
            funcionarios[i].nome = malloc(35);
            printf("\nDigite o nome do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].nome);
            printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].nome);
            funcionarios[i].email = malloc(35);
            printf("\nDigite o email do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].email);
            printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].email);
            printf("\nDigite a idade do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &funcionarios[i].idade);
            printf("\n%d", funcionarios[i].idade);
        }
    }   
    else if(opcao == 2){

    }    
    else if(opcao == 3){
        printf("Digite o numero do funcionario que deseja editar: ");
        int numero;
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        printf("Digite o novo nome: ");
        scanf("%34s", funcionarios[numero].nome);
        printf("Digite o novo email: ");
        scanf("%34s", funcionarios[numero].email);        
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente estas linhas não deveriam estar dentro do `if`, deveria inicializar antes de tudo e depois fazer o trabalho de manutenção no *array* criado.

```
printf("Quantos funcionarios deseja cadastrar? ");
scanf("%d", &qtdeFuncionarios);
Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(qtdeFuncionarios * sizeof(Funcionario));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/DynamicArray.c).

O erro acontece porque esta variável está dentro de um bloco que tem um [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) definido, nada declarado ali dentro vale pra fora.

Pra falar a verdade este código não deveria usar alocação dinâmica, pode ser que é algum exercício mandando fazer isto, mas se até o escopo está tão limitado é um desperdício fazer essa alocação, criando complexidade onde não precisa. E o exercício acaba ensinando fazer algo errado para o caso. Parece um erro ingênuo mas minha experiência indica que as pessoas fazem uma vez errado e aí fazem sempre.

Eu tinha arrumado tudo na resposta anterior, é triste ver que já começou bagunçar de novo :(

Olhando outras perguntas deste usuário esta resposta é inválida. Há um requisito não descrito. Não deveria pedir antes quantos funcionários serão cadastrados, apenas iniciar uma declaração da variável como nula e não alocar nada, depois fazer relocações conforme for cadastrado novos funcionários.