# Ponteiro acessado dados indevidos

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Estou com dificuldade para implementar a lógica de introdução de novos funcionários no código abaixo. Ao determinar a nova quantidade e realocar o vetor com base  nela, o primeiro novo funcionário está aparecendo com a posição adiantada ou atrasada ou o programa está encerrando

[image: como fica a execução].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
char *nome;
char *email;
int idade;
} Funcionario;

int main() {

int i, opcao, qtdeInicialFuncionarios, novaQtdeFuncionarios;

printf("Quantos funcionarios deseja cadastrar? ");
scanf("%d", &qtdeInicialFuncionarios);
Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(qtdeInicialFuncionarios* sizeof(Funcionario));

for ( i = 0; i < qtdeInicialFuncionarios; i++) {  

    funcionarios[i].nome = malloc(35);
    printf("\nDigite o nome do funcionario %d: ", i);
    scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].nome);
    printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].nome);
    funcionarios[i].email = malloc(35);
    printf("\nDigite o email do funcionario %d: ", i);
    scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].email);
    printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].email);
    printf("\nDigite a idade do funcionario %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &funcionarios[i].idade);
    printf("\n%d", funcionarios[i].idade);
}

while(1){

    printf("1.Cadastrar mais funcionarios\n");
    printf("2.Listar funcionarios\n");
    printf("3.Editar dados de funcionario\n");
    printf("4.Excluir funcionario\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    if (opcao == 1) {

        printf("Deseja cadastrar mais quantos funcionarios? ");
        scanf("%d", &novaQtdeFuncionarios);


        funcionarios = (Funcionario*)realloc(funcionarios, novaQtdeFuncionarios* sizeof(Funcionario));

        for ( i = qtdeInicialFuncionarios  ; i <= novaQtdeFuncionarios ; i++) {  

            funcionarios[i].nome = malloc(35);
            printf("\nDigite o nome do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].nome);
            printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].nome);
            funcionarios[i].email = malloc(35);
            printf("\nDigite o email do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%34s", funcionarios[i].email);
            printf("\n%s", funcionarios[i].email);
            printf("\nDigite a idade do funcionario %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &funcionarios[i].idade);
            printf("\n%d", funcionarios[i].idade);
        }
        qtdeInicialFuncionarios = (qtdeInicialFuncionarios + novaQtdeFuncionarios)-1;

    }




    else if(opcao == 3){

        printf("Digite o numero do funcionario que deseja editar: ");
        int numero;
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        printf("Digite o novo nome do funcionario %d: ", numero);
        scanf("%34s", funcionarios[numero].nome);
        printf("Digite o novo email do funcionario %d: ", numero);
        scanf("%34s", funcionarios[numero].email);
        printf("Digite a nova idade do funcionario %d: ", numero);
        scanf("%d\n", &funcionarios[numero].idade);

    }


}


return 0;
}
```

Eis o enunciado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo que entendo se você deseja cadastrar mais x funcionários então que realocar memória "acrescentando" mais x posições à sua área já alocada e não como fez onde você apenas realoca x posições sem considerar o que já foi previamente alocado.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Isto está piorando. Primeiro era pra escolher quantos funcionários ia cadastrar, agora está pedindo para adicionar novos funcionários? De onde surgiu este requisito que não tinha antes? Se é pra fazer isto então pra que pedir pra cadastrar antes? Eu reveria tudo isto.

Com a edição fica claro que tinha esse requisito, então não faz sentido começar a aplicação pedindo funcionários. De qualquer forma eu nunca respondi que deveria fazer isto mesmo sem saber deste requisito. Eu editei a [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410804/101) para refletir os requisitos postados aqui.

O grande problema é que parece que não está entendendo nada do que está acontecendo no código, e isto indica que não está aprendendo, ou está fazendo algo mais complexo do que está preparado agora. Inclusive voltou cometer erros que eu já havia arrumado antes.

Na condição não pode só ir até a quantidade nova de funcionários, tem que considerar a quantidade de funcionários já cadastrados antes também, em certas quantidades nem iria fazer nada porque o número que está finalizando é menor que o número inicial. Curiosamente fez certo na hora de mudar o valor total de funcionários, ainda que poderia ter sido escrito de forma mais simples. Mas novamente, reveja se realmente vai fazer isto. E decida o que tem que fazer. Se começar fazer coisas aleatórias qualquer solução será errada. Algo assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < qtdeInicialFuncionarios + novaQtdeFuncionarios; i++) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Range.c).

Comment: O requisito sempre houve, só não havia sido explicitado nas perguntas anteriores.                           Estou particionando a solução com base em uma visão geral do problema.

Comment: Sem requisitos corretos você não obtém respostas corretas. Todas as suas perguntas estão erradas porque tinha requisitos e seu código não os seguia, então fez todas respostas ficarem erradas também. Especialmente a pergunta anterior perdeu completamente o sentido.