# Variável não está sendo encontrada

Tags: java, variáveis, while, declaração-de-variável

Por que o seguinte programa não funciona?

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exemplo008 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int soma =0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Digite um número (0 para sair):");
            int valor = teclado.nextInt();
            soma += valor;
        } while(valor != 0); //Aqui está dando erro.
            System.out.printf("\n A soma dos números digitados é: %d\n",soma);

    }
}
```

Na linha do `while`, a variável não pode ser encontrada. Esse exemplo foi usado na minha faculdade e está copiado corretamente.

Comment: É uma questão de escopo. Imagine que o escopo da variável local dentro do método vale até o "fecha chaves" do bloco em que ela foi declarada. Então, a variável `valor` só vale até a linha `soma += valor;`, pois logo depois encontra um "fecha chaves"; como o `while` do `do-while` está além dessa chave, a variável está fora de escopo/não existe mais.

Comment: Longe de mim dizer que você não pode escolher a resposta que quiser, mas como trocou a aceitação alguma vezes talvez não tenha escolhida a que deseja mesmo. Se é a que deseja pode deixar onde está, não tem problema, a não ser pelo fato dela não estar exatamente correta e passa uma informação equivocada para quem for ler aqui. Veja o [tour]. Você só pode aceitar uma resposta e a que você aceitar por último é a que ficará. Quer repensar qual vai aceitar? Quando tiver 15 pontos poderá votar em todas respostas da sua pergunta ou do site. Pode deixar esta se desejar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **do while** é composto de dois blocos de códigos:

- O bloco do **do**, contém o seu escopo próprio de variáveis que apenas existe nele.
- O bloco **while**, por sua vez, possui também o seu próprio escopo que apenas existe nele.

A variável *valor* apenas existe no scopo do **do** e não tem como você acessá-la dentro do escopo do **while**.

Agora... caso você declare ela **fora** do escopo do **do while**, como fez com a variável *soma* não tem problema.

Comment: Não existem dois blocos como está dizendo, até existem dois um do método e outro do `do-while` que é interno ao do método. o `do` não está separado do `while` ele é uma coisa só, um bloco é definido pelas chaves e não por um comando (em alguns casos a chave pode ser omitia, mas aí não é um bloco mais). A resposta está correta, mas faz confusão pelo motivo exato.

Comment: Obrigado, eu havia pensado nisso, mas achei que a faculdade não cometeria um erro tão bobo e haveria outro motivo. Mas pelo visto, o fizeram kkkkk

Comment: @Maniero, permita-me discordar quanto ao bloco de código. Existem sim dois blocos de códigos(o do e o while) e poderiam existir quantos mais eu desejasse, por exemplo eu poderia fazer, logo a abaixo do int soma =0;...  {int b = 10;}; e na linha seguinte System.out.println(b); e o "b" nunca será visível na chamada do método println();

Comment: Exatamente poderia existir, mas não existe, Curiosamente você explica no comentário como é realmente, mas na resposta escreve errado, seu comentário contradiz a resposta. Você sabe o que é um bloco e respondeu outra coisa.

Comment: Ah, sim, @Maniero, verdade! My Bad!

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa declarar a variável fora do laço, isso chama-se [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Quando declara a variável dentro do bloco ela só existe ali; o `while` está fora das chaves, certo? Então ele já é fora do bloco e só pode acessar variáveis declaradas fora dele. Assim:

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exemplo008 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int soma = 0;
        int valor = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Digite um número (0 para sair):");
            valor = teclado.nextInt();
            soma += valor;
        } while (valor != 0);
        System.out.printf("\n A soma dos números digitados é: %d\n", soma);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DQfIFv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/VariableScope2java). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/VariableScope.java).