# Qual a diferença entre uma variável global e uma variável global static?

Tags: c, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis, static

Qual é a diferença entre uma variável global e uma variável global estática?  Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numero = 5;
static int static_numero = 5;

int main(void)
{
    printf("numero: %d \n", numero);
    printf("static_numero: %d \n", static_numero);

    return 0;
}
```

Existe alguma diferença entre as duas variáveis? Se não há diferença então qual seria o motivo de uma variável global não poder ser inicializada em um arquivo `.h` quando dois arquivos `.c` fazem o `include`?

```
/* Isso em um arquivo .h */
int a = 5; // Da erro
static int b = 5; // Nao da erro

/* Arquivo .c 1*/
#include "arquivo.h"

/* Arquivo .c 2 */
#include "arquivo.h"
```

O `static` do código acima por algum motivo é obrigatório, quando dois arquivos `.c` fazem o `include`, mas não seria redundante usar o `static` uma vez que o tempo de vida dessas variáveis não vão alterar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global é um termo um pouco ambíguo. O tempo de vida de ambas é global, de fato.

Mas a visibilidade delas é bem diferente. A variável não local tradicionalmente declarada tem visibilidade realmente global. Mas quando ela recebe um qualificador `static` a visibilidade é apenas do arquivo fonte do código que ela está declarada, ou seja, somente funções contidas nesse arquivo poderão ver e acessar essa variável.

Então quando você coloca o `static` a variável deixa de ser totalmente global (não muda o tempo de vida) e permite que se use em arquivos diferentes o que você pensa ser a mesma variável, mas são duas diferentes, com mesmo nome, com escopos diferentes.

Ambas não são recomendadas na maioria das situações. Pode usar se for realmente necessário e souber muito o que está fazendo.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).